# Is it possible to install and use a printer in Azure Worker Roles?

Tags: azure

I'd like to know if it's possible to create and use a printer in Azure Worker Roles.

I do know that I can install printers with basic batch commands. So I could define a batch script that would run as a startup task.

something like:

`rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "printer" /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /r "file:" /m "printername"`)

**Question:** Can I use a printer to print to file, maybe to local storage? 
I do need the function to print to file or atleast to have a printer installed, because I have to get the [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) output from different installed printers.

Sadly I can not test it by myself. I do not have a CC to join the 90 days trial.

Comment: This sounds like not a good idea. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using the pcl output to support different bluetooth printer to print directly from android/ios apps without having external apps (like pdfreader, etc) installed . Azure VMs would to the job flawlessly but I'd like to try out worker roles instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you think it is possible on Azure VM it is definitely possible on Web/Worker roles.

What you need is a [StartUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) Task executed with elevated privileges (`executionContext='elevated'`). This startup task can be anything that *does not require UI* to run.